# Wordpress Public-Runnable PHP Script

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made a Wordpress plugin that requires a site visitor to browse to a .php file in a subfolder in the plugin.

However, I've noticed that if the visitor is not logged in, the PHP script redirects to a 404 page.

I need to stop this redirection, and allow the script to be executed.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't block PHP files with a 404 page by default. It could be your host, htaccess, or a variety of other issues.

Either way, you don't want to call the PHP file directly if this is a WordPress plugin. If you did call it directly, you would not have access to WordPress (for example, you cannot use get_option or bloginfo()).

Rather, you should include it using PHP's `include` function from within your plugin. See [plugin_dir_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) for information about getting your plugin's working directory.

You can hook a page to call your function pretty easily. For example:

```
function call_my_php_script() {
  if ( isset($_GET['myscript']) && $_GET['myscript'] == 'run' ) {
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'scripts/my-script.php' );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('init', 'call_my_php_script');
```

And then access your script via: http://example.org/?myscript=run

You may want to store your plugin directory in a global/constant variable, as the plugin_dir_path function only works for the original plugin file.

Comment: Hooking a page to call the script sounds like a great idea. I will try this out, thanks.

Comment: I was also wondering, if the PHP file, at the top, is including an instance of Wordpress, why would it be unable to call get_option? This is a one-off utility script that adds many Posts to the users site, and it works on some sites.